# meaning of 'There’s doing things'

Tags: sentence-meaning

This is an excerpt from [a fiction story](https://www.newyorker.com/magazine/2022/01/17/fireworks).

> People could get into total flaps about weddings. Frank knew this. It
> was common knowledge. But he’d never before faced the wedding of his
> own daughter. He’d spoken as if he’d already arranged this wedding
> many times, been present at it often, so this time he had it all
> sorted. **There’s doing things** and there’s having to do them again and
> again. Such thinking doesn’t, or shouldn’t, apply to weddings.

I wonder what 'There's doing things' in bold means here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The structure is [ *"there's" + X + "and there's" + Y* ], where X and Y are the same part of speech, like both noun phrases, or both adjectives or both verbs. In this case, they're both gerund phrases.

The meaning is *X and Y may seem like the same thing, but they're really not*. The phrasing does not explain why, but invites the listener to figure it out for themselves.

In this example, it means "Doing things (once) is not at all the same as doing those same things again and again."

A clearer example (only because I don't know what things this quote is talking about) would be:

> "There's putting your sister's kid to bed, and there's putting your own kid to bed."

On the surface, the two should be the same since they're both just putting a kid to bed, but the structure invites you to figure out what the difference is. For example, it could mean:

> Kids are much more cooperative with adults other than their parents, so it's easier to put your sister's kid to bed than your own.

But it could also mean:

> Kids will only fall asleep if they're with one of their parents, so putting someone else's kid to bed can be a disaster.